# jQuery working in Chrome console but not in Chrome Screen

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, wordpress

-I am customizing a plugin and I have to add a processing icon(button-loader.gif) while image uploading.

-I customized the plugin and every thing was ***working fine on Firefox***.

-***But when I tried on Chrome button-loader.gif is not showing while image uploading.***

-Here is the div in my php file which shows loader:

```
<div class="wdm-uploading">
<img src="<?php echo plugins_url('/images/button-loader.gif', __FILE__); ?>" />
</div>
```

-CSS file content:

```
.wdm-uploading {
    display: none;
}
```

-In my .js file I am showing div when file upload initiates and I hide it when upload completes.

```
jQuery(curr_img + " + .wdm-uploading").hide();
jQuery(curr_img + " + .wdm-uploading").show();
```

-***I ran same above jQuery from Chrome console, It's working. But not working in Chrome screen.***

***I repeat it works on Firefox and on Chrome console, but not in Chrome browser screen.***

Can anybody tell me why it is happening?

Comment: Wrap code in `ready` or move code to the end of `<body>`

Comment: @Tushar: I tried that but not working...

Comment: Can you post the code controlling the hide/show?

Comment: @Cruiser: Here is the [function code](https://jsfiddle.net/oLbd38rr/) which envokes when user clicks on "browse file" button. I mean on onChange="return wdm_upload_image(<?php echo $k;?> );"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working properly when I made ajax request async.

Answer (score 1):

My thought here is the problem lies with (curr_img + "+ .wdm-uploading") in your JQuery selector. The JQuery docs say that both your curr_img (#imageInput_x) and the .wdm-uploading need to be children of the same parent. Since I haven't seen your html code, I'm thinking this might be the issue and Firefox's implementation is simply overlooking the requirement.